# getPsc() returns -1 on Samsung devices. What can I do to get it to work correctly?

Tags: android, linux, gsm

I have researched and found out that Samsung doesn't implement the code needed for this function to work properly.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get it to work? I don't mind getting down and dirty and try to mess around with Samsung's RIL or kernel or whatever.

Furthermore, devices that have the field `[gsm.version.ril-impl] = Qualcomm RIL x.x` seem to return 0 when `getPsc()` is called. Devices with `Samsung RIL(IPC) x.x` return -1.

I really, really want to get it to work, it'll make my life easier and my company wouldn't need to buy new phones.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to download and apply this [patch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2ec0e6fe1e5382d93cb28c97d24c7b0a0387c8ee). Read the patch notes for more detail.

Comment: How exactly do I apply it? Sorry for being a complete noob.